# How Does the copy constructor in c++ work?

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor

How does the copy constructor work when i am not passing "const Class &obj" to the constructor when i passing "obj" into a function. i got this doubt as the book on i c++ is was reading just mentioned what a copy contructor was and how to implement it. but did not mention how it was being called. i am new to c++. i googled it but could not find out how it was being called. Thanking You in advance:)

```
class Line{

  public:
   int getLength( void );
   Line( int len );             // simple constructor
   Line( const Line &obj);  // copy constructor

  private:
   int *ptr;
};

// Member functions definitions including constructor
Line::Line(int len){
 cout << "Normal constructor allocating ptr" << endl;
 // allocate memory for the pointer;
 ptr = new int;
 *ptr = len;
}

Line::Line(const Line &obj){
  cout << "Copy constructor allocating ptr." << endl;
  ptr = new int;
 *ptr = *obj.ptr; // copy the value
}

void display(Line obj){
 cout << "Length of line : " << obj.getLength() <<endl;
}

// Main function for the program
int main( ){

 Line line(10);
 display(line);

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can form a `const` reference to a non-`const` object... it just means the accesses to the object through the `const` reference won't be modifying the object (unless they cast away `const` again, there's a `mutable` field etc.).

Comment: How does the copy constructor get called when i pass the object into a function?

Comment: What do you mean by "how"? It's being called by the machine instructions which are emitted by the compiler (just like with any other function). Unless you are asking about what those machine instructions are, it is not at all clear to me what your question is.

Comment: The simple act of calling `display(line);` when `display` expects a `Line` parameter by value forces copy construction.  (What you should be doing is writing `void display(const Line& obj)` and making the `getLength` function in `Line` `const`.)

Comment: when i do Function(obj) .. i am not passing anything to the copy constructor to be called...but the copy constructor has parameters. how is it being called?

Comment: The compiler is smart enough to look at `Line line(10); display(line);`, `display(Line obj)` and `Line( const Line &obj);` and know it needs to use the copy constructor to construct the `obj` parameter to display using the `line` variable.  It's required to do so by the C++ Standard.  So, you *are* passing `line` to the copy constructor, whether you know it or not....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The copy constructor is a special function. It is called automatically, by the compiler, under certain conditions. One of those conditions is when you have a non-reference parameter in a function, and you pass an L-value object as the argument to that function. The parameter is initialized using the copy constructor, and the argument which was passed to the function is used as the argument to the copy constructor.

The compiler does all sorts of things on your behalf, without you having to do them explicitly. This is one of those things, and it is in accordance with the rules of the language.

Comment: Thanks a lot! i've been breaking my head over this. and i thought i missed something regarding constructors while reading the book. sorry for the silly question :)

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Are you speaking generally? Or for the OP's specific case? Because that is certainly not the case generally, in C++11.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley ok, never mind. (you're referring to move construction it seems)